# Missing document text when using python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am using python-docx 0.8.6 and python 3.6 to preform a simple search/replace operation.

I'm having a problem where not all of the document's text appears when iterating over the doc.paragraphs

For debugging I have tried

```
doc = Document(input_file)
fullText = []
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    fullText.append(para.text)
print('\n'.join(fullText))
```

Which only seems to print out about half of the file's contents.

There are no tables or special formatting in the file. Is there any reason why so much of the document's contents cannot be read by python-docx?

**Edit:** the missing text is contained within a mail merge field if that makes any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mail merge field *does* make a difference. Unfortunately, `python-docx` is not sophisticated enough to know which "container" elements hold displayable text and which do not. So it only reports paragraphs (and tables) that are at the "top" level.

This is also a limitation when it comes to revision marks, for example, which have two or more pieces of text of which only one appears, depending on the revision marks setting (show original, show latest after edits, etc.).

The only way around it with `python-docx` is to navigate the XML yourself, although some of the domain objects in `python-docx` can be handy, like `Paragraph`, etc. once you've gotten hold of the elements you want.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to python-docx that are sophisticated enough to know which "container" elements hold displayable text? Or, is navigating the XML yourself the only option you know about?

Comment: @dshefman Have you found any answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
To view the text you can try
`paragraph._p.xml` this will get you xml contents where text should be

Then you can parse it with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(paragraph._p.xml)
soup.find_all("w:p")
```

This will get you a list with something like this

```
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:t>9.3. Some text...</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

Then you can just do

```
for el in soup.find_all("w:p"):
    print(el.text)
```